# The Hyperlink is not displayed with blue and underline by use the Outlook add-in

Tags: hyperlink, format, outlook-addin

I add a context menu item for new mail of Outlook, after select any text, use below method to add the Hyperlink. This works well in most conditions, but the hyperlink does not display with blue and underline in below two conditions. In the condition two below, the bullet or number is also deleted unexpectedly.

Two Condition:
1. No other character before and after the selected text, and there's lines(one or more, blank line or lines with characters)after the line which selected text is located.
2. Bullet or Number for the line which the selected text is located in. No other character before and after the selected text, and there's lines(one or more, blank line or lines with characters) after the line which selected text is located.

Code:

```
           Outlook.Application myApplication = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
            Outlook.Inspector inspector = myApplication.ActiveInspector();    
            Word.Document document = (Word.Document)inspector.WordEditor;


            object selectedText = document.Application.Selection.Text.TrimEnd('\r');
            object missing = Type.Missing;         
            object address = document.Application.Selection.Text.TrimEnd('\r');


           document.Application.Selection.Hyperlinks.Add(document.Application.Selection.Range, ref address, ref missing, ref missing, ref selectedText, ref missing);
```

Any of you met this situation before? Why this happened? Any fix way/workaround?